# What is the hanging comma for in this python matplotlib code?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In this [matplotlib tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_anim.html), we see:

```
x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
```

Why is there an extra `,` after `line` is instantiated? I noticed that an error will be produced without the comma.

Initially, I thought that we were dropping the second item of two items that are being unpacked, although after running `a, = (3,4)` and getting an unpacking error I no longer believe that.

Thoughts?